# Main electric service & range hood vent

Tags: electrical, venting

I'm in the midst of a reno on my kitchen, which involves some reconfiguring of the placement of appliances. As a result, where the stove is going - and hence the range hood / blower vent location would come through the roof right near where the main electrical service attaches to the house and runs to the main panel.

My question is this: is there a minimum recommended / required distance between the range hood vent location and the main electrical connection coming from the utility to the house (I'm in CA if there's state specific code on this)? Its a very shallow pitch roof so I'm unable to elbow & run the ducting through the attic to come through the roof elsewhere. If I need a minimum separation I'll probably have to run a chase along the ceiling inside the kitchen to come through the roof far enough away from the electrical main.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'd get the best answer calling your local code inspector's office since they will need to approve what is done anyway.

Comment: Usually, the utility will provide these specs. For example, PG&E has requirements for the service entry for both gas and electricity

Comment: Usually 3' from chimneys is required measured vertical, diagonal and horizontal is required per NEC 225.19.B , I have seen vents below the service drops in the past and they may have measured 3' virticaly but this is the closest to a specific measurement I could find.

Answer (score 1):

NEC 110.34 (F) says, "pipes or ducts foreign to the electrical installation and requiring periodic maintenance or whose malfunction would endanger the operation of the electrical system shall not be located in the vicinity of the service equipment, switchgear, or industrial control assemblies. Protection shall be provided where necessary to avoid damage from condensation leaks and breaks in such foreign systems..." Beyond this, I don't see anything else in the NEC that might speak to your issue. It doesn't sound like your installation plan would endanger the operation of the electrical system, but that is a question you will have to answer. I did a web search for California building codes but turned up nothing that specifically addressed your situation.